# Split string on commas but ignore commas within double-quotes?

Tags: python, regex, string, csv, split

I have some input that looks like the following:

```
A,B,C,"D12121",E,F,G,H,"I9,I8",J,K
```

The comma-separated values can be in any order. I'd like to split the string on commas; however, in the case where something is inside double quotation marks, I need it to both ignore commas and strip out the quotation marks. So basically, the output would be this list of strings:

```py
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D12121', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I9,I8', 'J', 'K']
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Lasse is right; it's a comma separated value file, so you should use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). A brief example:

```
from csv import reader

# test
infile = ['A,B,C,"D12121",E,F,G,H,"I9,I8",J,K']
# real is probably like
# infile = open('filename', 'r')
# or use 'with open(...) as infile:' and indent the rest

for line in reader(infile):
    print line
# for the test input, prints
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D12121', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I9,I8', 'J', 'K']
```

Comment: You could fix the issue with spaces after the commas by passing `skipinitialspace=True` to `reader`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a regex based solution, a simple one could be to split on comma (`,`) or characters between quotation marks (`"(.*?)"`); then filter away empty values.

```py
s = 'A,B,C,"D12121",E,F,G,H,"I9,I8",J,K'
splits = list(filter(None, re.split(r',|"(.*?)"', s)))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D12121', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I9,I8', 'J', 'K']
```

Another could be to call `re.findall()` with a pattern where either characters between quotation marks (`"(.*?)"`) or non-comma characters (`([^,]+)`) are captured. It creates a list of 2-tuples where one of the values is an empty string; so just joining these tuples would do the trick.

```py
splits = list(map(''.join, re.findall(r'"(.*?)"|([^,]+)', s)))
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D12121', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I9,I8', 'J', 'K']
```

That said, I do believe the standard `csv` library is the best solution here. Note that `csv.reader` expects a list of strings, so if you want to split a single string, wrap it in a function.

```py
import csv
splits = next(csv.reader([s]))
```